# How to create tables dynamically in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Hey can anyone tell me how can i create tables dynamically in GAE.I want to create a friend list like in Facebook where i can store the details of my friends.Likewise everyone will have a table of their own.I cannot make a single table because if someone is my friend he might have people who are not my friends so why should i store their details.
 I've searched a lot but not found anything.
Also please suggest some alternatives if possible.

Comment: perhaps you should start with a tutorial as your question does not make much sense TBH. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/ and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

Comment: It would be possible to create tags for a generic table with polymorphic fields - your question is a bit broad for a definitive answer though

Comment: I have the same question for which I couldn't get the answer any way I want to add some more.  I am using Objectify api to create database table (we call it KIND ) and to make queries. So I want to create a "Kind" (table) dynamically (run time). Is it possible? If possible please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use namespaces.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

For an example of dynamic table creation, you can look at Google's ShardedCounter class at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters to see how the name of the table (really Entity in GAE) can be composed at runtime.